# Python u-law issues: unknown format: 7

Tags: python, numpy, format, fft, wav

I'm trying to compare two large sets of wav files to remove duplicates.  The issue is that one set is PCM, the other has been u-law'd.  When I try to read in PCM wav, no problem, but the u-law files give the following error:

```
>>> wav = wave.open("C:\\soundfiles\\Olympus Recordings\\1019.wav")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\wave.py", line 497, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\wave.py", line 163, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\wave.py", line 143, in initfp
    self._read_fmt_chunk(chunk)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\wave.py", line 259, in _read_fmt_chunk
    raise Error('unknown format: %r' % (wFormatTag,))
wave.Error: unknown format: 7
```

So I look in wave.py and find:

```
 def _read_fmt_chunk(self, chunk):
        wFormatTag, self._nchannels, self._framerate, dwAvgBytesPerSec, wBlockAlign = struct.unpack_from('<HHLLH', chunk.read(14))
        if wFormatTag == WAVE_FORMAT_PCM:
            sampwidth = struct.unpack_from('<H', chunk.read(2))[0]
            self._sampwidth = (sampwidth + 7) // 8
        else:
            raise Error('unknown format: %r' % (wFormatTag,))
```

Does this mean python only handles un-ulaw'd wavs?  I don't know enough about audio to want to try hacking my python.

I can play both kinds of files no problem, but looking at ulaw'd files in GSpot shows I'm missing codecs.

[image: Codec NOT installed]

Any ideas?  Maybe don't use python?  I like that numpy has a Fast Fourier Transform, I'd rather not try writing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html) (emphasis mine):

> The `wave` module provides a convenient interface to the WAV sound format. **It does not support compression/decompression**, but it does support mono/stereo.

You will need to find a module that actually supports decompressing audio.